# Java mongo driver bulk operation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to do a bulk operation using the mongo-java driver, the main idea is to insert the documents if an id comes null or to update otherwise. the insert operation is working but when it comes to the update the changes are not applied (i already tried an upsert operation but it didn't work).

Here is my code:

```
public BulkWriteResult bulkStockUnitUpsert(List<StockUnit>stockUnits) {
        BulkOperations ops = mongoOperations.bulkOps(BulkMode.UNORDERED, StockUnit.class);
        for (StockUnit stockUnit : stockUnits) {

            if(stockUnit.getId() != null) {
                Query query = new Query();
                query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(stockUnit.getId()));
                Update update = new Update();
                update.set("price", stockUnit.getPrice());
                update.set("product", stockUnit.getProduct().getId());
                update.set("quantity", stockUnit.getQuantity());
                update.set("sku", stockUnit.getSku());
                update.set("variant", stockUnit.getVariant());
                ops.updateOne(query, update);
            } else {
                ops.insert(stockUnit);
            }
        }
        return ops.execute();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by the upsert operation not working?

Comment: it doesn't insert or update the documents

Comment: Check the actual error response in the write result, and of course check you are actually providing a list in the first place. If you are providing something, then include some sample detail in the question as well as any detail obtained in the actual `BulkWriteResult` response. But we need the details here in order to answer.